# I try to do callout to my apex rest service from first to second dev org, but got CalloutException

Tags: apex, api, callout, rest, proxy

```
String endPoint = 'https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/getAccounts/';
Http h2 = new Http();
HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
req1.setMethod('GET');
req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);

String trimmedResponse = res1.getBody().unescapeCsv().remove('\\');
system.debug('@@@RESPONSE@@'+trimmedResponse);
```

Error on line 10, column 1: System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"
AnonymousBlock: line 10, column 1

**Postman works fine, but I cant do the same with apex**
[image: Postman works fine, but I cant do the same with apex]

Comment: Hello Ivan, and welcome to SFSE (Salesforce Stack Exchange). Quick question: are you sure the endpoint is correct? I tried to open https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.salesforce.com/ but it failed with a DNS error.

Comment: The first thing I would check here is to see if you do actually have the Apex class with `@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/getAccounts/')` in the org you're making this callout to.

Comment: @DerekF in Postman everything is fine

Comment: @JefersonChaves you need access token to call my apex rest, this URL for rest service , you can login with this URL https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/

Comment: Hello Ivan, thanks, but actually the endpoint on Postman is different from the code. I see the postman as https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com and the code with https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.salesforce.com (missing the .my. between dev-ed and salesforce). Suggestion: copy the endpoint from postman and update the code, try again, and report the outcome.

Comment: @JefersonChaves ,it works ,what a stupid mistake, thanks)

Comment: It happens to us all. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint on the code is missing `.my.` between the `dev-ed` and `salesforce`.

From https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.salesforce.com to https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com.

So, replace the endpoint into the code to:

```
String endPoint = 'https://wise-otter-ngj5eu-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/getAccounts/';
```